# When subscribe failed, the go client return nil

Tags: go, mqtt

```
if token := c.Subscribe("go-mqtt/sample", 0, nil); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
    fmt.Println(token.Error()) 
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

EMQ server return reasonCode=128, the go client's Error is always nil,we can't get EMQ server's suback.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from ALSM on the paho.mqtt.golang issue you [initially commented on](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/issues/380#issuecomment-873883869):

> Yeah, this was an interesting one, a subscribe can have multiple topics in it, and the subacks return success/error for each of those topics in a single response. It would be simple to have the client detect if all of the response codes in a suback are failure and set the error on the token, but less clear is what to do in the case of a mix of success and failure.
> It's an open question, any thoughts welcome.

The approach the library takes is to consider a subscription request that has have been processed (a `SUBSCRIBE` was sent and a `SUBACK` received) to be successful. It gives you the option to check the responses to the individual subscriptions if you so desire (but does not raise an error response if 1-many of the requests failed). As ALSM commented there may well be better approaches to this (and suggestions would be welcomed).

You indicated that this was not working for you but have not provided any additional information (as requested) here so it's difficult to know what you are struggling with. Here is one approach to give you the general idea (have not compiled/tested):

```
token := c.Subscribe("go-mqtt/sample", 0, nil)
if token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
    fmt.Println(token.Error()) 
    os.Exit(1)
} 
if t, ok := token.(*mqtt.SubscribeToken); ok {
    subResult = t.Result() 
    rc := subResult["go-mqtt/sample"]
    fmt.Println("SUBACK response: ", rc) 
} else {
    fmt.Println("unexpected token type") 
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: thanks, i've  got the return code,  the code token.wait()&&token.Error() works, i didn't use it before, so the result was  empty.